# How to read in datetime with a format different from the default?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, datetime

I'm using this command to read in a csv file with date time:

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv",parse_dates=['TimeFrame'])
```

What is in column 'TimeFrame' is in a slightly different format than default:

This is the format in the csv file:

```
1,2021-04-01_13:47:31,30.0,35.375,20.725,20.416,32.830,0.000
```

Python didn't recognize the "_" (underscore) between date and time. The imported data is formatted as `str`. The problem is resolved if I manually change the "_" to " ".

How to avoid this extra step and have python understand "_" directly during the import step?

Answer (score 2):

you need strptime(). Check it out here: [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).
You can do something like (not exactly sure...)

```
timestamp = datetime.strptime(your_date, "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%m:%s")
```

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) has a `format` argument for manually specifying date format.

```py
import sys
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = StringIO("""id,date,1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2021-04-01_13:47:31,30.0,35.375,20.725,20.416,32.830,0.000
    """)

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=',')

print(df.dtypes)
"""
id        int64
date     object
1       float64
2       float64
3       float64
4       float64
5       float64
6       float64
dtype: object
"""

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')

print(df.dtypes)
"""
id               int64
date    datetime64[ns]
1              float64
2              float64
3              float64
4              float64
5              float64
6              float64
dtype: object
"""
```